# Eclipse GIT Repo Multi Module - Adding a new project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

Using eGIT I can successfully clone a GIT repo.

I can also import (as maven module), the multi-module project (by selecting the parent pom) into eclipse. As per best practise, my local workspace and GIT repo are in separate directories. I can make changes to existing classes / packages (i.e. add, commit and push to GIT origin on GitHub), and am starting to understand the GIT workflow...

What I cant figure out is how to add a new java project to the multi-module project? Should I create in GitHub first?

Other Config:
- Local GIT repository (i.e. where I created clone):

> > c:\dev\gitrepos\xxx-api-client.git

- Local Workspace (i.e. my workapce where I imported clone into - which btw is ):

  > > c:\dev\apis
- I do have write access to then GIT repo

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you are using Maven as a build tool ,then I don't think you have to add separately in your repository , GIT will automatically take care of that.

Only thing you have to do create a new module and declare that in your parent pom file like this.

```
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>  
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>your_new_module</module>   </modules>
```

Now next time when you do a commit , you have to add this pom file. From there onwards it will be a part of your repository and whenever anybody do a clone it will be available.

Please correct me if i have not understand your question correctly.

Comment: Ok so say I have "your_new_module". Are u saying that all i need to do  such that this project is created, is add a reference to the parent pom file and then commit / push this file? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure which IDE you are using , if you are using eclipse and having maven plugin installed in it .. then you can create a new module and during the creation time it will ask you to enter the parent maven project under which you want to create it so that it will inherit all the dependencies from it.

After this an empty maven module will be created , and when you commit these changes you will see a new pom.xml file , that you have to add.